# if statement in Django crispy form, conditional form layout

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django crispy form: A typical sign up form with email address, password field and submit action.

I have a hidden field passed to the Django crispy form from my urls python file called 'billing_secret". The billing secret is different for different URLs.

objective:
To have a terms and conditions radio checkbox enable/disable the submit button for a specific billing secret, consequently url.

I need to add 2 things.

1. Add an if statement within the Crispy form to only show a Radio checkbox for a certain billing secret. For example, if the billing secret is "apples" **show** radios and default to "no". If the billing secret is anything else make the radio hidden, default to yes.

This is what I have so far (doesn’t work). Apologies I’m completely new to Python.

```
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"))
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label=_("Password"))
billing_secret = forms.CharField()
termsandcond = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label = "Do you agree to the T&C's?",
        choices = ((1, "Yes"), (0, "No")),
        coerce = lambda x: bool(int(x)),
        widget = forms.RadioSelect,
        initial = '0',
        required = True,
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    billing_secret = kwargs.pop('billing_secret', None)
    super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.form_action = '.'

    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('email', placeholder=_("Email")),
        Field('password1', placeholder=_("Password")),
        Field('billing_secret', value=billing_secret, type="hidden"),

        if billing_secret is 'apples':
            return InlineRadios('termsandcond'),
        else:
            return InlineRadios('termsandcond', initial="1", type="hidden"),

        Submit("save", _("Get Started"),css_class="pull-right"),
    )
```

2. Disable the submit button when the radio buttons value is  ”no" and enable when "yes".

I plan on including this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8YBu5/7/

That way a user must agree to the T&C's when signing up before being allowed to submit their details if on on the specified url with the billing secret is “apples”. If they are on a different url, the radio does not exist and the submit button is enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the button by default hidden:

```
Submit("save", _("Get Started"),css_class="pull-right", style='display: none;')
```

And do the checking for the radio button with javascript, when the user click on accept just select the button and show it.

EDIT:
For conditional elements:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('email', placeholder=_("Email")),
    Field('password1', placeholder=_("Password")),
    Field('billing_secret', value=billing_secret, type="hidden"),
)

if billing_secret is 'apples':
    self.helper.layout.append(InlineRadios('termsandcond'))
else:
    self.helper.layout.append(InlineRadios('termsandcond', initial="1", type="hidden"))
self.helper.layout.append(Submit("save", _("Get Started"),css_class="pull-right", style='display: none;'))
```

Comment: yes but I need the radios to be only in the form for a specific billing_secret. So my first question was how do I add form elements conditionally based on the billing_secret variable. Once i figure that out I should be able to enable/disable the button with JS. thanks for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add a conditional layout is with a custom function.

```
def layout_if(condition, *args):
    if condition:
        return args
    else:
        return ()
```

Which can then be used in the layout. Pay attention to the asterisk which is needed to convert the return values to separate arguments.

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('email', placeholder=_("Email")),
    Field('password1', placeholder=_("Password")),
    Field('billing_secret', value=billing_secret, type="hidden"),
    *layout_if(billing_secret is 'apples',
               self.helper.layout.append(InlineRadios('termsandcond'))),
    *layout_if(billing_secret is not 'apples',
               self.helper.layout.append(InlineRadios('termsandcond', initial="1", type="hidden"))),
    self.helper.layout.append(Submit("save", _("Get Started"),css_class="pull-right", style='display: none;'))
)
```